# When cache false in set in ajax,it add some value in request what it is

Tags: ajax

I using a small code of Ajax and my code is working.There is no error in my code but when i set cache false in my ajax it add some value in request.I want to know What is the value and its purpose.

My code is

```
function validate() {
    var user = $('#user').val();
    var num =  $('#num').val();
    var mobile=  $('#otp').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  "/validateOtp",
        data: {user: user , num: num , mobile: mobile},
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success : function(response) {
                alert( response );
            },
            error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
    });
}
```

it generate request like this in browser

```
http://localhost:8080/validateOtp?user=1234&num=12345&otp=1234&_=1528862398631
```

you can see the value added by ajax **&_=1528862398631**

and My backend code is in Spring MVC

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/validateOtp")
public class ValidateOTPAjaxController {
private final Logger logger = 
 LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

@Autowired
private OTPService otpService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public String getAllDistrict(@RequestParam(value = "user") String user,
        @RequestParam(value = "num") String num, @RequestParam(value = "mobile") String mobile) {
    logger.debug(user);
    logger.debug(num);
    logger.debug(mobile);
    return "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the cache property to false jQuery will append a timestamp to the URL, so the browser won't cache it (as the URL is unique for every request. See the documentation for details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And your controller should be like following:

```
@Controller
public class ValidateOTPAjaxController {
   private final Logger logger = 
   LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

   @Autowired
   private OTPService otpService;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/validateOtp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getAllDistrict(@RequestParam("user") String user,
        @RequestParam("num") String num, @RequestParam("mobile") String mobile) {
      logger.debug(user);
      logger.debug(num);
      logger.debug(mobile);
      return "OK";
  }
}
```

Comment: @SudhirOhja Thanks for answer but Controller is not working in backend.How can call controller.Can u help me.

Comment: @SudhirOhja I am using Spring MVC

Comment: Ya..It is working logger print value but browser show 404 error in this url